# Issues with running typescript app on elasticbeanstalk due to ts-node-dev not found

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nodes

on EB it seems that there is no ts-node-dev installed by default which is weird. How is it possible to force EB to install ts-node-dev on the EC2-instance it fires up?

Here is my log:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR!     /home/webapp/.npm/_logs/2020-12-25T06_49_47_444Z-debug.log
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: > testapp-01@1.0.0 dev /var/app/current
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: > ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./src/server.ts
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: sh: ts-node-dev: command not found
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! syscall spawn
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! file sh
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! testapp-01@1.0.0 dev: `ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./src/server.ts`
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR!
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! Failed at the testapp-01@1.0.0 dev script.
Dec 25 06:49:47 ip-172-31-32-184 web: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I'm sure I missed something out as I'm quite new to EB. Any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Which exactly EB platform version are you using?

Comment: Node.js 12 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.2.3